# Android - Change background color of specific item of ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

I'm making a game which will use a `Listview` to display some text as a chat.

Some of these texts represents *events*, so I want to change their background color according to that specific event:
EX. Somebody gets killed, **that specific `Listview`'s item will have a *red* background color**

How do I achieve this?

This is my JAVA code:

```
            //STARTING SETUP
        ArrayList<String> arrayListMother;
        ArrayAdapter<String> arrayAdapterMother;
        ListView listViewMother;

        int counter;
        boolean introDone = false;

        String[] night = {"Welcome!","This is Lupus In Tabula!","You're gonna experience the Hasbro Game in a total new way, have fun!"};
        String[] day = {"Thank you!","Great","Let's do it!"};
        String[] dead = {"Thank you!","Great","Let's do it!"};
        String[] saved = {"Thank you!","Great","Let's do it!"};

        Button buttonGo;
        //ENDING SETUP


        //CREATE - CREATE//
        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_game);
            setup();

        }
        //CREATE - CREATE//


    public void setup(){

    arrayListMother = new ArrayList<String>();
    arrayAdapterMother = new ArrayAdapter<String>( this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListMother);
    listViewMother = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_mother);
    listViewMother.setAdapter(arrayAdapterMother);
    buttonGo = (Button)findViewById(R.id.buttonGo);
}
```

And this is my XML code:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical">

<ListView
    android:id="@+id/list_mother"
    android:text="@string/go"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:textAppearance="?attr/textAppearanceListItem"
    android:divider="@null"
    android:layout_weight="7"/>

<Button
    android:id="@+id/buttonGo"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:text="@string/go"
    android:textColor="@color/white"
    android:background="@color/colorPrimary"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:onClick="play" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: You can do that easily with the model class having setter and getter for Color and with the position ( index of listitem)

Comment: May I ask for an example @Raghunandan

Comment: You will get a better solution if you post your code first. Atleast the relevant part of what you tried

Comment: Sure thing, edited @Raghunandan

Comment: Not working @Raghunandan

Comment: It should work. Show us your updated code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Override `getView` for `ArrayAdapter`. Based on the condition change color or do what is required. You have already provided params to `ArrayAdapter` constructor. So there is no need to inflate the view again. Get the same and do what is required. Similarly `getItem(position)` get's the data at a specidifed position.

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.html#getItem(int)

```
listViewMother.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, arrayListMother) {
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = super.getView(position, convertView, parent);

    if(getItem(position).equals("Somebody gets killed"))
    {
       // do something change color
       row.setBackgroundColor (Color.RED); // some color  
    }
    else
    {
       // default state
       row.setBackgroundColor (Color.WHITE); // default coloe
    }
    return row;
  }
});
```

Comment: Hey, how would I get automatically the int of the current position of a new item I'm gonna add? I'm creating a redEvent() method that takes as params a String for the message and then it should turn the background of that item in red, how do I get the position or focus on that item? Thanks

Comment: You get the current position of the item in getView. see the first param. If you are adding new item you can added to the list. getItem(Position) will get the item at that position which is a string and compares it with SomeBody gets killed if equal the background will turn red

Comment: Yeah, the fact is I want to turn red the item not by comparing the Strings, but istantly when I add them with a method say "redEvent()". So the question is, outside that adapter, how do I get the position of the new item I'm creating in the same time?

Comment: Answer is getview. Add new item with string and call adapter.notifyDatasetchanged() to refresh

Comment: Add a new item and refresh list view. Getview will do the job

Comment: But what if I don't wanna achieve that with text? Is there any other way?

Comment: Check documentation for arrayadapter you might find something

Answer (score 6):

use this code:

```
listViewMother.getChildAt(position).setBackgroundColor(
            Color.parseColor("#00743D"));
```

Answer (score 1):

In your adapter class where you are binding the view, you can check for the particular condition and set the color in following way.This way you can set the color of the text or background dynamically. Hope this helps.
I am using recycler viewer here which over rides onBindViewHolder. Your adapter should have the method which binds view.

```
@Override
 public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {
     Person person = personList.get(position);

     holder.username.setText(person.getName());
     holder.arriveTime.setText(DateFormat.format("hh:mm a",(person.getArriveTime() * 1000)));


     if(person.getName().equals("NoVisitor"))
     {
         holder.username.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
         holder.arriveTime.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
         holder.leaveTime.setTextColor(Color.GRAY);
     }
     else
     {
         holder.username.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         holder.arriveTime.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
         holder.leaveTime.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
     }
 }
```