# Android ListView Change Row Color On Value (not on Select)

Tags: android, listview, firebase

Everything is working. i.e. Data is read from Firebase and displayed in the FirebaseListAdapter.

Here is the code in question

```
        int urg = model.getUrgency();
        if(urg == 1) v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

Problem is it randomly colors more rows red than it should. i.e For my test I made only 1 record have urg = 1. Yet when I scroll, more than 1 rows turn red. How do I fix?

```
private void refreshListView(){

    fbAdapter = new FirebaseListAdapter<Post>(this, Post.class,R.layout.post_message, query) {
        @Override
        protected void populateView(View v, Post model, int position) {
            TextView messageText = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_text);
            TextView messageTime = (TextView)v.findViewById(R.id.message_time);

            messageText.setText(model.getMessageText());
            messageTime.setText(shortTime.format(model.getPostTimeStamp()));
            int urg = model.getUrgency();
            if(urg == 1) v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
        }
    };

    mListView.setAdapter(fbAdapter);
    mListView.requestFocus();
}
```

Comment: Problem solved here:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34706585/android-change-background-color-of-specific-item-of-listview

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for red color in more than one row is, there is no else block. Add an else block will fix this issue.

```
 int urg = model.getUrgency();
 if(urg == 1){
     v.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
 }else{
     v.setBackgroundColor(Color.WHITE);
 }
```